# $RECYCLE.BIN question that is not a duplicate marked as a duplicate

Tags: support, status-completed, exact-duplicates

[Oliver Salzburg♦](https://superuser.com/users/36744/oliver-salzburg) marked my question...

> [How to delete $RECYCLE.BIN folder on external hard disk?](https://superuser.com/q/564442/78538)

...as a duplicate of...

> [There is a “$REYCLE.BIN” folder in my external hard drive; can I delete it?](https://superuser.com/q/314092/78538).

Apparently Oliver did not care to read my question, as I explicitly *link* to the question he thinks mine is a duplicate of. That question does not answer my question. That question asks if it is okay to delete the recycle bin folder, whereas I ask *how* to delete that folder since I cannot see it. The answers are also completely different.

I could have formulated the title as *How to delete special folder from hard disk* and then it may have never been marked as a duplicate, but the question would remain the same. So, this is what I get for being specific in the title.

I ask my question to be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

The questions are sufficiently different & as such I've reopened it.